# Bifurcation flow field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

assuming I have

$$x'=5+mx+2x^2$$

how would I find the flow field of this bifurcation with the changing variable m?

**EDIT:**

Take for example 
http://www.math.colostate.edu/~shipman/47/volume3b2011/M640_MunozAlicea.pdf

At page 2 there is a very strange looking diagram that is a parabola upside down. I don't see how he would draw that. I understand that the axes are shift but like what is the thought process? How would I also draw a flow diagram etc... please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing we do is to set $x'=0$ and find the critical points. This yields:

$$x'=5+mx+2x^2 = 0 \implies x=\frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{m^2-40}-m\right), x=\frac{1}{4} \left(+\sqrt{m^2-40}-m\right)$$

Now, we can do a plot in the $xm-plane$ for the first root, yielding:

[image]

Doing a similar $xm-plane$ plot for the second root yields:

[image]

The major difference between these and the ones you reference in the book is that you typically find where the points are stable and unstable and use a dashed line to designate where the system is unstable and the solid line stable. I will leave you to do some of the work.

Now, if we were to draw a direction field plot of the system while varying $m$, you can observe that we transition through a change. The RHS and LHS behave the same for the two roots above. Here is an animated direction field plot.

[image]

Lastly, it is worth mentioning that we can find a closed form solution to this system as:

$$x(t)\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{20-m^2} \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(c_1 \sqrt{20-m^2}+\sqrt{20-m^2} t\right)\right)-m\right)$$

Try plotting $x$ as a function of $t$ for different initial conditions and what do you notice.

**Update**

We can also write $x' = 5 + mx + 2x^2, ~ y' = -y$ and do a phase portrait since you asked for that animation. I will let you do the analysis. Here is the parametrized ($ -15 \le m \le 15$) phase portrait.

[image]

Comment: my bad you have drawn the flow-field as an animation. If u take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC2w2z_i2DA you will see that it is done by hand in way I am not familiar with. can you please explain?

Comment: Also similarly it is illustrated here in page 4 http://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_6.pdf

Comment: But how do you find the direction of the flow?

Comment: Yes, in a similar way it was illustrated in the video.

Comment: The animation "brings it all home"!